# React native setState updates array with empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a class constructed as follows -:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      guestsStore:[],
    };
  }
```

And I have a form that takes a text input and that is supposed to add the submitted name to the guestsStore array by calling `this.handleNameSubmit`

The following code doesn't work even if I have seen it in multiple code examples. It updates state but with an empty object-:

```
  handleNameSubmit = (name) => {
    this.setState({
      guestsStore: [...this.state.guestsStore, name],
    });
  };
```

The following code works and updates state with the name.

```
handleNameSubmit = (name) => {
    this.setState({
    guestsStore:[...this.state.guestsStore, {name:this.state.name}],
    })
  }
```

I am new to React Native and would like to understand why this happens. Why in this case does the first code example fail even if it works in so many other cases

Comment: What are you expecting state to look like after the call to `handleNameSubmit`?

Comment: How does `name` get passed to `handleNameSubmit`? How is `handleNameSubmit` called? Also, not an answer to your question but you shouldn't use `this.state` in `setState` because updating of state can be deferred and create unexpected results, use "prevState". ie. `this.setState((prevState, props) => ...`

Comment: @ksav I expect an array of guest objects: [{name:guest 1}, {name:guest 2}]

Comment: @rshepp on button press in the form that takes text input for name.

Answer (score 1):

These two approaches accomplish different things.

```
 handleNameSubmit = (name) => {
     this.setState({
         guestsStore: [...this.state.guestsStore, name],
     });
 };
```

This code adds field `name: name` to the expanded array `this.state.guestsStore`, and then assembles the array into `guestsStore` of the new state.

```
handleNameSubmit = (name) => {
    this.setState({
        guestsStore:[...this.state.guestsStore, {name:this.state.name}],
    })
}
```

This code adds object `{name: this.state.name}` with a field to the expanded array `this.state.guestsStore` and then assembles it into `guestsStore` field of a new state.

You need to make sure you understand the difference between the two and use the one that you need in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much Evgenii! Your description makes the distinction clear — I see why I had to pass an object with its field in the second case because the array started out empty without a data structure. When I tried the first case on fetched data that was already structured, it worked!

Comment: @Kat Happy to help :)